# How to find where an app was installed?

Tags: 18.04

Using Linux Ubuntu 18.04. I have installed Android Studio and when the installation was completed application launched itself and I exited. Now I can't find the app or a way how to start it.

How can I start Android Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install a debian package, you can see where everythings are located by issuing the dpkg with -L

```
dpkg -L <package name>
```

That will list where all files in the package are installed. For metapackages, you it will not show you much beside a copyright file and change log. So you need to issue the above to the actual packages.

Note: If that doesn't help, try locating studio.sh, the start script for studio.

```
locate studio.sh
```

Comment: when i try to locate nothing happens

Comment: You may want to describe how you installed the studio as there are several ways to do it. See if you have ANDROID_HOME or ANDROID_SDK_ROOT defined, that will give you a clue as well. Try "env |grep ANDROID"

Comment: I have Android/Sdk file on my Home page, but there is no sign of studio.sh, i think im gonna install it again and on the initial launch of app put it as a desktop

Comment: I have managed to start it again when starting the installation, I shouldn't delete the extracted folder? Looks so.. thanks for the help :)

Comment: np, the studio installation is flexible so you could've installed it in any directory. The sdk root should be configured for you, so don't delete that path.